# Format on Prolog

Tags: prolog, format, tabular

I have a doubt making tables with format, I need to make tables, I know I can make it this way:

If for example my table is `tabla("estudents",["name","age","id"])`.

But I have a problem, I need to get the numbers of attributes of the table, then I'll set a length of 18 to each square and the length will be N..

```
print_table_name(C):- tabla(C,A),                //I SEARCH MY TABLE
                  atom_codes(Name,C),            //PASSING THE NAME TO ATOM
                  length(A,N),                   //I GET MY NUMBER OF ATRIBUTES
                  Length is 18*N,                //Length WILL BE THE LENGTH OF THE TABLE
                  print_edge(N),                 //HERE I PRINT THE TOP EDGE
                  format('|~t~a~t~N|)|~n',Name), //HERE IS MY ERROR
                  print_edge(N).                 //HERE I PRINT THE BOTTOM EDGE

print_edge(0):- format('~n',[]).
print_edge(N):- format('+~`-t~18|+', []), M is N-1, print_edge(M), !.
```

`format('|~t~a~t~N|)|~n',Name)` here I can't pass N as a variable, then I dont know how I can do to format get the N, N is the length of the table..
It print this

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|students
||
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and if I put the length where is N, then it works.

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                 students                                 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The problem is that I don't know how to pass the variable N to format.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should pass N as an argument to the [`format/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=format/2) predicate. Replace the variable N in the format by the symbol * and put N in the argument list.
I'm not sure if you will get the desire effect, but at least it won't fail.

```
format('|~t~a~t~*|)|~n',[Name, N]).
```

### Edit

Right now I can only test the solution in this limited [online interpreter](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/): I replace the `~t` by the character dot `~46t` to see the effect and this is the result:

```
?- format('|~46t~a~46t~*|)|~n',['students', 72]).
|...............................students................................)|
```

PS: Are you sure about the parenthesis between the two last vertical bar?